# Windows Explorer replacement which allows creating custom file properties

Tags: windows-explorer, file-management

I'm looking for a Windows Explorer replacement that has the following feature in some way or another:
The ability to create custom properties for files.
by saying properties, I refer to fields like "Size" or "Date Modified" which all files have or "Date Picture Taken" which jpeg has.

I want to be able to take an arbitrarby file, give it a new property, assign a value to it and later be able to sort or search files according to their properties.

Of course, I'm not suggesting to modify the files in any way - I'm aware of the fact that a metadata file should be automatically created by the program to store the info.

The reason I came up with this need is the discomfort of typing these properties in the filename itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some search I've found a way to add new columns to windows explorer.
The following link has helped me: (I wanted to post more links but since I'm new user it won't let me)

[File Rating - a practical example of shell extension](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/columnhandler.aspx)