# Column properties satisfying certain conditions

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, filesystems, file-management

My OS : windows 10

I am looking for column properties of windows explorer (which means size, type, modified date, etc) that meet the following conditions:

1. completely separated from its content(file content)
2. exist for every file
3. can be edited for every file (possibly by some software). The editing should be done without changing file content.
4. Preserved when copied or moved.

For example, 'bit rate' does not satisfy 1),2),3) but satisfies 4) because

- window explorer reads header (header is a subset of file content, of course) of a music file to get bit rate.
- bit rate doesn't exist for txt file.
- bit rate cannot be edited without changing file content.
- bit rate of two files are the same if two files are same.

More examples :

- modified date satisfies 1),2),3) but not 4)
- size satisfies 2),4) but not 1),3)

I am looking for (all) column properties satisfying all 1),2),3),4).

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: PS) If assigning picture width to a txt file were possible, I would accept the answer gladly. Whether it fits to common sense or not is not important here.

Comment: @ Wasif Hasan : If there is such column property, I can insert and deal some short useful information without changing file content.

Comment: I don't think there are any.

Comment: See [c# - Custom File Properties - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632612/custom-file-properties)

Comment: You will need to write a shell extension. [Windows Explorer replacement which allows creating custom file properties - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/184063/windows-explorer-replacement-which-allows-creating-custom-file-properties)